# How to reduce objects of a commutative diagram to the elements of those objects

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let's say we have two functions doing completely different things; however, their (co)domains are exactly the same as follows:

$f: X \rightarrow X$ (*)

$g: X \rightarrow X$ (**)

Let's also assume that $X$ includes 4 objects as $X:=\{a,b,c,d\}$.

In my particular (engineering) application, there is an interesting relation between the cited functions and **some specific elements of the (co)domains** as below (A):

[image]

In my recent report, I called the diagram above a commutative diagram, but my supervisor said this is not a commutative diagram since the (co)domains of $f$ and $g$ are not as already stated in (*) and (**). On the other hand, if I observe that if I rewrite the diagram in the form of the main (co)domains, I end up with (B)

[image]

which is neither a commutative diagram nor what I intend to present.

To be specific, what I need is to consider particular (co)domain objects instead of whole (co)domains in the commutation, but my formulation sucks. Can you please guide me to fix the problem? For example, can I simply call (A) as a `functional diagram`, instead of `functional commutative diagram`? Or say the (A) is a **reduction** of (B)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need category theory to "quantify" this?  Your top image merely says
$$
g(f(a)) = f(g(a))
$$
which is (a) already pretty clear and simple and (b) understood by every mathematician in the world.  If you needed to say these compositions agreed on more points than just $a$, you could just write
$$
g(f(x))=f(g(x)) \text{ for all } x \in X'
$$
where $X'$ is the subset of $X$ that you want $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ to match on.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No problem.  Anytime.